# AWS ECS Fargate with an Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I am using ECS Fargate to execute java code in threads. Is it possible to have an ALB stop sending requests to a Fargate task once I have a certain number of java threads running in that task? And then, as my threads finish I would allow the ALB to send another request.

I see an ALB performs health checks and if an task fails a health check the task is temporarily put out of the target group. But I don't see a way I would be able to utilize this as these health checks are timed(not checked before every sent request) and there is no way to manually send a fail signal.

Does anyone know a way in which I could force ALB to stop sending requests to a task once I have my set limit of threads in that task met.

Comment: no there's no way to do this

Comment: @MarkB thanks for getting back to me - that's what I found as well after looking just wanted to be sure. Could I ask you another question then - with the aws alb LOR algorithim if my java thread is passed a socket object(from the alb request) and uses it to pass multiple pieces of data back(through alb) does LOR routing algorithm look at when that socket is closed or only after the first response. Thanks and sorry for bothering you with this is a comment

Comment: I have no idea. That sounds like an implementation detail an AWS employee might need to answer.